# SoundPool load method inside onclick

Tags: android, onclick, soundpool

i want to load a SoundPool inside onClick, but when i use:

```
c = sound.load(this, R.raw.ak47s, 1);
```

I get an error: the method load in a SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments.

I know i can't use "this" inside load, so what to use ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is done in the Activity ExampleActivity, you should write:

```
c = sound.load(ExampleActivity.this, R.raw.ak47s, 1);
```

You need to fully-qualify this, as it is in an enclosed class instance.

Comment: OK, but still, how to load soundpool inside OnClick method ?

Comment: Should be the same, except of the change I made.

Answer (score 0):

use getApplicationContext() instead!

Comment: Can you show me how to use it ? When I just type it in onClickListener it's not working...

Comment: u might be using "this" kwyword inside onClickListener object..
replace "this" with getApplicationContext()